# Trouble with getting cookies Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to read cookies in laravel 5.3 from ajax function?

I set cookies from ajax:

```
Cookie::queue('test', $test, 900)
```

Is all ok, in index controller there is no problem to see the result:

```
$data = Cookie::get();
debug($data);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [XSRF-TOKEN] => m84KsCPi9C68OLY21arp1Ha9qltPsKNNXKBfnxJ6
    [laravel_session] => e656c82742a87563f1b3835035ea5fd877380fb1
    [test] => gGTBoeXzcxdYnmjv2Nkt
)
```

But when i tried to run exactly the same command in another ajax function, the result is:

```
Array
(
    [test] => 
    [XSRF-TOKEN] => m84KsCPi9C68OLY21arp1Ha9qltPsKNNXKBfnxJ6
    [laravel_session] => e656c82742a87563f1b3835035ea5fd877380fb1
)
```

My ajax javascript call:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': here_is_generated_token
    },
    method: form.attr('method'),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: { 
        form_data: form.serialize() 
    }
 }).done(function( msg ) {
     console.log(msg);
 });
```

I tryed to do the same with hidden input {{ csrf_field() }}, the is no progress.

Why i can set, but can't read? Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried injecting the `$request` into your Controller's AJAX method?  You can access cookies from the request as such: `$request->cookie('test')`.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#cookies

Comment: Nope, there is the same result:

Comment: Is your AJAX route defined in  `routes/api.php` or `routes/web.php`?  Might be related to the middleware that is defined for each.